# Try to pass $ref data to prop data of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I have a component Carousel, and I have method:

```
carousel () {
  return this.$refs.carousel
}
```

When I try pass to prop of other component, I get undefined in prop data, why?

```
<Dots :carousel="carousel()" />
```

In child component I have:

```
export default {
  name: 'Dots',
  props: ['carousel']
}
```

In mounted when I try call `console.log(this.carousel)`, I get undifined. But I need get a component data of Carousel. How I can do it?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-monad-5bhjz?file=/src/components/Test.vue

Comment: what's the value of `this.$refs.carousel`. Also try to `:carousel` from a computed value instead of calling to a method

Comment: @RavishaHesh value of this.$refs.carousel is: VueComponent {_uid: 16, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}

Answer (score 1):

You can set a function in `carousel` to return the `data` you want to send to `dots`. Then, in the parent component, set its return value to an attribute in `data` which will be passed as a `prop`:

```js
const dotsComponent = Vue.component('dotsComponent', { 
  template: '#dotsComponent',
  props: ['carousel']
});

const carouselComponent = Vue.component('carouselComponent', { 
  template: '#carouselComponent',
  data() { return { id:1 } },
  methods: { 
    getData() { return { id: this.id } } 
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { dotsComponent, carouselComponent },
  data() { return { carousel:null } },
  mounted() { this.carousel = this.$refs.carousel.getData(); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div><carousel-component ref="carousel"/></div>
  <div><dots-component :carousel="carousel"/></div>
</div>

<template id="dotsComponent"><p>Dots: {{carousel}}</p></template>

<template id="carouselComponent"><p>Carousel</p></template>
```

Comment: Carousel is component of the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-carousel, I need send all data.

Comment: @RedFox you can wrap it in your own ``carousel`` component and do the above

Comment: I know, But I don't need wrap in carousel, My dots navigation are outside the slides, in a completely different block

Comment: Didn't fully get your point. But from what I understood from your question, your ``carousel`` component can be set as a custom one you create and import this library and set it in the components section. This way you have it wrapped, and do the above by sending the data from the imported ``vue-carousel`` component

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OxwctvU See please, My dots pagination in other block. I can't wrap carousel component in this block, because this is other block. And so I need send ref data to a component Dots

Comment: By wrapping I mean, create a separate ``carousel.vue`` component having the content of ``.carousel-clients-works``. This way, you can return ``this.$refs.carousel`` in its ``getData`` method and then pass it in as a prop as you're doing in the parent component.

Comment: Before component it is not working. I get undefined if I pass data in prop before component.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the ref directly without using a method any other property :

```
 <Dots :carousel="$refs.carousel" />
```